# Custom middleware causes a circular reference in redux

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-middleware

I am trying to convert a redux project to typescript using the provided documentation:

https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-middleware

However I'm having trouble doing it with my custom middleware. Here is the minimized and extracted code that causes an error for me.

store.ts:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import reducer from './customReducer';

import { customMiddleware } from "./customMiddleware";

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        custom: customReducer
    },
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(customMiddleware)

})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

export default store
```

customMiddleware.ts:

```
import { Middleware } from 'redux';
import { RootState } from './store';

export const customMiddleware = (): Middleware<{}, RootState> => {
    return store => next => action => {
        return next(action);
    }
}
```

This causes several error messages:
on `const store = configur...`:

'store' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

on RootState export:

Type alias 'RootState' circularly references itself.

on customMiddleware export:

'customMiddleware' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that case, you'll have to somehow break the circle.

Easiest way here is

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof customReducer>
```

---

Edit: I think your initial code here was     `reducer: customReducer`

With the given code it won't work - you need to split out that reducer creation before the store creation:

```
const rootReducer = combineRecucers({
        custom: customReducer
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(customMiddleware)

})
```

Comment: Well, first there are more reducers, not just customReducer. I just made a small example. Second, if I pick one of those it doesn't work. Now it throws that there are no matching overloads when I prepend the customMiddleware.

Comment: Ah OK, makes sense. If I try this I get the errors on prepend. Argument of type '() => Middleware<{}, RootState, Dispatch<AnyAction>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Middleware<any, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>' and also Argument of type '() => Middleware<{}, RootState, Dispatch<AnyAction>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly Middleware<any, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>[]'\

Comment: I tried changing `export const customMiddleware = (): Middleware<{}, RootState>` to `export const customMiddleware = (): Middleware<{}, RootState, Dispatch<AnyAction>>`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, OK I figured it out. The problem was in how I was defining my customMiddleware. The documentation simply defined the export as a Middleware:

```
export const customMiddleware: Middleware = store => next => action => {
    return next(action);
}
```

But I had my export as a function that returns a middleware, since there's some initialisation there in my actual code:

```
export const customMiddleware = (): Middleware => {
    return store => next => action => {
        return next(action);
    }
}
```

So I simply had to call it as a function when prepending:

```
middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(customMiddleware())
```

Very silly of me...

EDIT: using a root reducer type was needed as well.